# Opening a form, within another form

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have seen applications where there is a main form...and forms that could be opened within the main's canvas but cannot be dragged out of the main form at all.But could be maximized while still remaining within the "main" form. I have googled this but everyone is just trying to open one form from another which is not what i want to do.

Comment: Are you talking about MDI forms? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xyhh2e7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I assume this is a desktop application.  Are you using winforms or wpf?

Comment: @xxbbcc i checked out your link, it *looks* like what i am looking for but i am not too sure yet since i dont even know what those type of applications are called. But i will keep reading the KB

Answer (score 1):

use an MDI Form, make the MDI Form your startup form, then to show the child form use the code below in the MDI Form's load event or any other event you want:

```
childform.MDIParent = Me
childform.Show()
```

and that's it :)

Comment: shouldn't it be a child if it's being opened inside the parent? i haven't tried the code but i will

Comment: yes it's a childform if that's what you want to call it, it's just a normal form though
BTW if you can't find the MDI Form you can just create a basic windows form and find isMDIForm or MDIForm in the form's properties and set it to true

Comment: hey could you please check the wording of your original answer? i find it hard to understand...please use terms such as child and parent. The startup form (doesn't have to be startup) "mdi parent form " would be the form i want other forms to appear in. Then child mdi forms would appear in that parent mdi form. Now, how would you set the parent-child relationship within code? i see your snippet but don't really understand your wording